# Which one to use for implementing Edge Analytics? Apache Edgent or Kaa?

Tags: iot, kaa, apache-edgent

I have came across the term **edge analytics** in recent times and understood the advantages of pushing intelligence to edge devices. Now coming to implementation, I have gone through **Apache Edgent** and **Kaa**. Both seems to perform more or less similar job for me with respect to analytics on edge devices, but Kaa is entirely a platform for IoT which has edge analytics as a feature. Which is more efficient and used in the industry?

Comment: Which one of [key Kaa features](http://docs.kaaproject.org/display/KAA/Kaa+IoT+Platform+Home) do you treat as edge analytics?

Comment: I am considering profiling and grouping feature of Kaa as edge analytics. Is that equivalent to filtering out known information and send only information which is of our interest ?

Answer (score 2):

You can filter your devices to [endpoint groups](http://docs.kaaproject.org/display/KAA/Using+endpoint+group%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bs) that can have different configurations and notification topics, what allows you to treat EP differently by condition matches. But there are no mature analytic tools  like Spark to write some background jobs that perform data processing on collected information from endpoints.
In future release 1.0.0, this feature is being planned to add into Kaa platform.